# i want create date validation but not know why return is false?

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, date

i want create date validation but not know why return is false?

```
$data_go = '2011/04/28';
$ddmmyyy='(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- \/.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- \/.](19|20)[0-9]{2}';
            if(preg_match("/$ddmmyyy$/", $data_go)) {
               return TRUE;
            }else {
              return FALSE;
            }
```

Comment: Try to get the variable $ddmmyyy out of the string to avoid confusion with a regex when not remembering that there was a variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your date is yyyy/mm/dd, while your Regex is dd/mm/yyyy.

Answer (score 1):

i'm not much familiar with regex (shame on me) but you can always use the [checkdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) method to validate a date server side.

In your case you do:

```
if (strpos($data_go, "/") !== false) {
    $date_exploded = explode("/", $data_go);
    if (checkdate($date_exploded[1], $date_exploded[2], $date_exploded[0])) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: how is date validation for year, month, day each separate?

Comment: why do you want to validate them separately?

Comment: if typed wrong in input year, month, day return false. if date typed in input less of date now (date submit) return false. how is it?

Comment: if you want to also compare dates, have a look at [mktime](http://php.net/mktime) & [strtotime](http://php.net/mktime)

Answer (score 0):

The following regex matches your date and others like it.

```
([1-9][\d]{3})[- \/.]([0-1][\d])[- \/.]([0-3][\d])
```

Explanation

The first group `([1-9][\d]{3})` is the year and allows for the range 1000 to 9999

The second group `([0-1][\d])` is the month and allows for the range 00 to 19 (obviously it won't catch bad months)

The third group `([0-3][\d])` is the day and allows for the range 00 to 39 (again, it won't catch bad days)

Once you have those parts you can do explicit validation using more appropriate tools than regex, or just use a [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) object to start with, and don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: how is date validation for year, month, day each separate?

Comment: I've added an explanation for the regex

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to match all possible dates?  As @nomulous pointed out, the pattern matches mm/dd/yyyy, not yy/mm/dd.  I'd go with checkdate to verify the date, and use \d in place of [0-9] for simplicity.

Comment: how is date validation for year, month, day each separate?